# Angular 8 resolver is not resolved

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-resolver

I have console.log in constructor and ngOnInit() of Resolver but which are not logged.

> resolve:{serverResolver:ServerResolverDynamicDataService}},
>
> console.log("ServerResolverDynamicDataService constructor");
>
> console.log('ServerResolverDynamicDataService resolve:'

```
const appRoutes : Routes =[
    {path:"",component:HomeComponent},
    {path:"servers",canActivateChild:[AuthGuardService],component:ServersComponent,
        children:[                
          {path:":id",component:ServerComponent,
           resolve:{serverResolver:ServerResolverDynamicDataService}},
          {path:":id/edit",component:EditServerComponent,canDeactivate:[CanDeativateGuardService]}]},
```

**Resolver:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerResolverDynamicDataService implements Resolve<ServerModel>{

    constructor(private serversService:ServersService){
        console.log("ServerResolverDynamicDataService constructor");
    }

    resolve(activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerStateSnapshot: 
        RouterStateSnapshot): ServerModel | Observable<ServerModel> | Promise<ServerModel> {
            console.log('ServerResolverDynamicDataService resolve:'+activatedRouteSnapshot.params['id']);
        return this.serversService.getServer(+activatedRouteSnapshot.params['id']);
    }    
}
```

**Update1:** app.module.ts has entry of this service in providers

```
  providers: [ServersService,AuthGuardService,AuthService,CanDeativateGuardService,ServerResolverDynamicDataService],
```

Whenever URL(`http://localhost:4200/servers/1?allowToEdit=0&allowTest=2#loadPage`) is getting hit, no logs are coming from resolver but logs are there in code and the application is properly refreshing if I edit any other part of the application log. So app changes are reflecting the only problem is resolver is not called.

**Update2**
As per [Angular 2+ route resolvers not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651242/angular-2-route-resolvers-not-being-called) if I remove parent canActivateChild service which is working.B ut I don't know what is wrong.Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

A Resolver is a service and `OnInit` isn't executed in a service. In fact, besides `OnDestroy`, there's no other lifecycle hook in a service.

Anyway, I'm assuming your resolver is provided somewhere. If it's not, you should use an argument in its decorator: `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})`.

Comment: Thanks for reply,Service is registered in app.module as  providers: [ServersService,AuthGuardService,AuthService,CanDeativateGuardService,ServerResolverDynamicDataService],